# Unable to change the position of label C#

Tags: c#, forms, location, label

I can't change the position of label in the following code:

```
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        var F = new Form
        {
            BackColor = Color.Black,
            TransparencyKey = Color.Black,
            Bounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds,
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Location = new Point(0, 0),
            MinimumSize = new Size(1920, 1080),
            TopMost = true
        };

        var Summoner1 = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            Text = "Summoner Flashs in 20",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
            Location = new Point(0, 500)
        };
        var Summoner2 = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = true,
            Text = "Test",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
            Location = new Point(40, 20)
        };
        var Summoner3 = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            Text = "Summoner Flash in 20",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
            Location = new Point(0, 0)
        };
        var Summoner4 = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            Text = "Summoner Flash in 20",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
            Location = new Point(0, 0)
        };
        var Summoner5 = new Label
        {
            AutoSize = false,
            Text = "Summoner Flash in 20",
            Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
            ForeColor = Color.White,
            Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
            Location = new Point(0, 0)
        };
        F.Controls.Add(Summoner1);
        F.Controls.Add(Summoner2);
        Application.Run(F);
    }
```

I have the code in there:

```
          Location = new Point(0, 500)
```

but it seems to be appearing at 0, 0 regardless of what I put in there, which makes it look like only the Summoner1 label initializes, not the rest of them (I've tried just with Summoner1 and Summoner2). What's the problem with it?

Answer (score 1):

Remove DockStyle.Fill. This property will expand your label to Fill the form regardless of the location you set. Filling means starting from location 0,0 through the size of the form

The same is true for the other labels. At the end the last rendered by the form engine will cover all the others

```
    var Summoner1 = new Label
    {
        AutoSize = true,
        Text = "Summoner Flashs in 20",
        // Dock = DockStyle.Fill,
        ForeColor = Color.White,
        Font = new Font("Consolas", 12),
        Location = new Point(0, 500)
    };
```